# Spring XD module without any annotation and xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

How to create Spring xd module without any xml file and annotations, just pure java?
What is xd data flow to write a module for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "pure" java - XD modules are [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) applications and need the infrastructure it provides.